# How to output to a file and get the specific header file in cURL?

Tags: linux, unix, curl

I have a file link that I'm going to download with using cURL and I need to output this file to some temp file also I need to get the specific header value.

Example:

```
Link: http://my.download.url<br>
Output to: /tmp/my-downloaded-file<br>
Header(Content-Length or whatever): abc123
```

Comment: Provide an exact output from which you want to extract your contents

Comment: @Inian I want to copy the output in a file(the path that I'm going to provide) with the name of content-disposition.

Comment: Fair enough! and what do you want to do after writing to it? Provide an example

Comment: @Inian I'm gonna get the name and run the file in my prod.I need that name because it passes as a parameter to some function.

Comment: I don't see a question here, you can just do `curl -s <url-here> > <name-of-your-file>` to do this? Is that what you intend to do?

Comment: @Inian I'm using OS X

Comment: What is your expected output? Provide a verifiable input and expected output.

Comment: I need to get the value of header[Content-Disposition] and use this value for file name for the output.Then also I need to provide path for the output.When I type curl command like this: curl bla-bla /my-temp-path my-link.And the output will be:  /my-temp-path/value-of-content-disposition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the file name depends upon the value of a header?

cURL, as far as I know, doesn't allow you to get the headers on one stream (say standard out) and the body on another. What you need to do is either get all of them together and parse it out, or perform two calls. Here is the two call approach:

```
# URL and the header you want
url="http://www.example.com"
hdr="Content-Length"

# get the value of the header (this does not download the body)
headerValue=$(curl -sI "$url" | grep -i "^$hdr:" | cut -f2 -d: | sed 's/^[ \r\n\t]*//;s/[ \r\n\t]*$//')

# create a file name from that header value
fileName="/tmp/download-$headerValue"

# download the body into that file
curl -so "$fileName" "$url"
```

Comment: The first call performs a `HEAD`, which downloads *only* the headers. The second call performs a `GET`, which downloads the headers *and* the body.

Comment: Oww got it so it does NOT download 2 times.Thank you!

Comment: And what if the header has changed between the header download and the body download?

Comment: @malhal A good question, but one that's between the API consumer and the application. HTTP doesn't guarantee atomicity or consistency.